# Saving functions of x that are not being optimised for optimisation matlab fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, plot, fminsearch

I have a function with two outputs as such

```
function [cost,correlation] = opt(beta, data, ind)
```

I am minimizing the cost function, using options with `fmincon` I can plot `beta` and `cost` at each iteration and they are saved. How can I do the same with correlation (even though it is not part of the optimization, I would like to track this)

Comment: Do you want to plot the value of `correlation` during the optimization (i.e. after each iteration), or just see the change when the iteration is finished? Also, how do you currently save and plot `beta` and `cost`?

Comment: yes I would like to plot it after each iteration and have it saved. I currently use options to plot cost and beta    options = optimset('PlotFcns',{@optimplotfval,@optimplotx},'MaxIter',10);

Answer (score 0):

You can define an output function that fmincon will call at every iteration. Details [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-function.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/output-functions.html)